# MySQL Select Children (Tree/Chain Structure)

Tags: mysql

I have created comments for my site which are all stored in one table regardless of the subject being user, post, photo or whatever. For which I have created a column named `type` and the types being respectively `0 = user`, `1 = post`, `2 = photo` and so on. But I have also decided to add the option of replying to comments and it being indefinite. So simply I added a `reply` column to the table which holds the ID of the comment that the given comment is a reply to. If a certain photo's comments are to be displayed I select them like so

```
SELECT `stuff` 
FROM `opinions`
WHERE `type`=2
```

and then, say some comments have replies to them, and to get those I firstly have to check if each single comment has any replies at all, and if yes then send another SQL request to fetch the replies and do the same thing for the fetched replies and so on and so on and this seems a little.. Well wrong. Can someone lead me to the path of righteousness and show me the light please?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `opinions` (  
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `reply` int(11) NOT NULL,  
    `recipient` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `sender` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `opinion` text NOT NULL,  
    `time` int(11) NOT NULL
)
```

**EDIT**: Thank you guys for the help but all of this seems so complicated and I can't seem to understand how to implement it since I have unlimited number of children and most of the examples given have numbers of children and stuff. Unless somebody is willing to spend their time to explain this to me like to a complete idiot, I'm going to just have ajax calls to load replies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913595/chain-select-query

Comment: Can you please elaborate I can't seem to understand how I would apply this to my case

Comment: OP, this is what I would do before I started using a framework (CakePHP) and also my server doesn't allow me to run queries like that because I guess I'm lacking certain permissions (like to perform "set") so this might not be the solution for you as well.

Comment: I think you want something like this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609328/mysql-query-for-selecting-children  I haven't used nested queries for a few years, but if I remember right this should help.

Comment: @JoelLewis This seems so complicated, really makes me feel like a beginner. But at least I can now google nested queries for noobs and hope for some 101 tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like `connect by prior` in oracle See this post, this should help you.

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

Also you could use [Tree Order Traversal](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) alghoritm (you can find it also on wikipedia), but it requires recalculation of `left` and `right` values everytime you add/delete something to/from your table

Answer (score 1):

You could use a MPTT or also known as Nested set table
http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Good for read queries bad for write/update :)

Comment: Hmm, didn't you just copy this link from my post? :D

Comment: I was just teasing with this :) You're totally right with reading vs write/update. I implemented this once, but in case where there were much more reads than updates. That's why I mentioned this recalculation...